# Pyomo Optimization of minimum cost using binary variables

Tags: python-3.x, binary, gurobi, pyomo

I have an optimization problem where I want to minimize for the total cost of a system, so I write an objective function that is the sum of my different costs. The problem includes using one of three machines each one with different cost at a different threshold of usage. I define each machine (model.Machine#) as a binary variable and declare the parameters of each machine cost model.Cost#). I am trying to get the cost to be able to minimize it but when I write the constraint:

```
model.Cost1*model.Machine1 + model.Cost2*model.Machine2 + model.Cost3*model.Machine3 == model.MachineCost
```

Where I also write:

```
model.Machine1 + model.Machine2 + model.Machine3 == 1
```

Gurobi is telling me that it can't handle an quadratic function referring to the first constraint mentioned above. However it is parameters multiplied by binary variables there isn't anything quadratic.

I know the question is vague and part of a larger problem but I hope you can understand what I am referring to and help me!

Thank you so much for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

What is `model.MachineCost`? Is it an Expression component with some kind of quadratic expression stored inside of it?

If not, can you start commenting out things in your model until you get down to a minimal working example (that causes this error) and post that? Otherwise, we can't be sure that there are not other quadratic pieces of the model that you are not showing.